# script to run search on website and return results

Tags: python, r, search

I am interested in automating the following process for a systematic literature review which I am conducting.

I have a substantial list of disease causing agents and I want to run a batch search on the medical literature and return how many results I get from each type of bug, then put these in a nice CSV file so I can read them into R and crunch some stats/frequency distributions etc.

I could do this all with an excel sheet and CTRL C + CTRL V but it would take some time.

Basically I need some way to talk to [OvidSP](http://ovidsp.uk.ovid.com/) which hosts the databases I want to search, then feed in a string formatted correctly for the exact search I want to do. Then have OvidSP run the search for me, and return how many hits it gets. I guess this would be easy if they had an API available - I have emailed them directly about this.

I wondered if anyone thought this was at all possible or what would be the best way to program a script for this task. I have some experience with Java, C++ and starting to learn R - I wondered also if Python could be of use?

This is a quick illustration of what I hope to achieve

bugs i want to search for (fed into program via CSV file lets say)
* Salmonella
* E. coli
* Influenza

insert fancy program here which connects to Ovid with my credentials and runs the following searches

1 - Salmonella AND fever AND hospital   - returns 9342 results
2 - E. coli AND fever AND hospital      - returns 93821 results
3 - Influenza AND fever AND hospital    - returns 323 results

program writes this data in a nicely formatted CSV file that I can use for some stats

I hope that makes sense! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable in principle, the big issues are going to be parsing the return data (potentially hard, potentially easy), and authentication (probably not hard, but depends on the structure of their site).

the python modules you want to look into are [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (for the requests), [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) (for the csv), and [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

the nice thing about writing this in Python is that you can explore the returned html interactively (in the python shell) and so have an easier time of figuring out how to extract the small amount of interesting data from the html you'll get back.